# Back to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I downloaded Windows 8 release preview. and I forget to burn a bootable cd (I know a big mistake). The last time I wanna back to Windows 7 I deleted Windows 8 partition and I reboot my PC but the system ask about BOOTABLE CD, and I haven't got it. And my PC still work and boot with Windows 8.

I have 4 CD installation Windows 7 and my recovery partition D:15,8 GB still in my PC.

What can I do to delete and have Windows 7 back?

HP dv6 pavilion...64bits

Comment: So answer this since I can't quite get it out of your question, you installed 8 over 7 this time or you installed 8 on a different partition and you can't boot into 7 for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

At the HP welcome screen tap the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to launch the recovery process. Follow the instructions provided on the screen.

If the recovery partition no longer works or is not accessible, you can order a set of recovery discs from HP thru this: [Looking for Recovery Discs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&cc=us&docname=bph07143)